# Connectiong Google Data Studio to Cloud SQL gets internal error

Tags: looker-studio

I am trying to connect data studio to a MySQL second-generation instance in Google Cloud SQL.  I am using a JDBC URL like this:

```
jdbc:mysql://104.xx.yy.zz/prod
```

But keep getting this:

```
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.
```

Has anyone else seen this?

Thanks for any tips or pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved: the following IP addresses needed to be added as authorized networks in the Access Control section of Cloud SQL.  Really wish Google would say something like "connection refused" rather than "internal error".

```
64.18.0.0/20
64.233.160.0/19
66.102.0.0/20
66.249.80.0/20
72.14.192.0/18
74.125.0.0/16
173.194.0.0/16
207.126.144.0/20
209.85.128.0/17
216.239.32.0/19
```

Comment: See official list here : https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7088031#notes

Answer (score -1):

I think that previous list is missing a couple IPs. Here is a more comprehensive list:

```
64.18.0.0/20
64.233.160.0/19
66.102.0.0/20
66.249.80.0/20
72.14.192.0/18
74.125.0.0/16
108.177.8.0/21
173.194.0.0/16
207.126.144.0/20
209.85.128.0/17
216.58.192.0/19
216.239.32.0/19
```